# What are acceptable characters that can be used in the template?

Tags: android-pay

In the Wallet Objects template, what characters can I use? I do not want to accidentally use characters that are not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acceptable UX string characters are: a-zA-Z0-9!@#$^%&*()[];:'"<>,./?-_=+ (and space, newline as '\n' and backslash as '\'). To create a break you need to use newline (\n). HTML tags are not supported.
You can also insert special characters such as © ® by copy / pasting into the fields of your Loyalty or Offers class or object. Most unicode characters such as \u00ae \u00a9 are also supported.